# How to run a KarateTest.Jar?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, karate

I have created a jar file comprising all Karate test cases of my project, now how do run it? i was able to run the tests in eclipse using Junit now i'm trying to integrate karate tests in Jenkins CI pipeline jobs and am not sure how to do this.

I checked if the jar had the test cases of the project and it did.

```
 root@mymachine:# unzip -v api-tests.jar

  Archive:  api-tests.jar

Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----

    0  Stored        0   0% 04-08-2019 05:43 00000000  META-INF/

   389  Defl:N      226  42% 04-08-2019 05:43 131755ce  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

    0  Stored        0   0% 04-08-2019 05:43 00000000  examples/

   747  Defl:N      445  40% 04-08-2019 05:43 8adc3e2f  examples/ExeTest.class
```

Ran the below command to execute the Test Jar. Running the command in the test jar's directory.

```
root@mymachine # java -cp api-tests.jar:/usr/share/java/junit4.jar junit.textui.TestRunner com.cape.board.api.examples.ExeTest


Class not found "com.cape.board.api.examples.ExeTest"
```

So how do i execute this and is there anyother way to integrate Karate in Jenkins pipeline job.

Comment: You should run the java command from the root directory

Comment: Are your tests part of your project or they are separate?

Comment: @Spara I tried running in the root directory too by specifying the path of the testcase jar..throws the same error.

Comment: @IvanLymar from the project i created separate jars for actual code and for tests and i hope this jars contains only test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify class in cmd is  `com.cape.board.api.examples.ExeTest`, but you packaged the class into `api-tests.jar`  is `examples/ExeTest.class`. That's why report class not found.

Comment: Thanks Yong, i'm able to run the jar. It throws the below error now..so it means my Karate feature files are not included in the Jar or i should specify something else to identify those Karate test cases?


.F
Time: 0.001
There was 1 failure:
1) warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in examples.ExeTest

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1,  Errors: 0